# How to skip fatal error from PHP

Tags: php

This is a demo code in the `line 6` there is a function `find()` actually this function doesn't exist and when i run this file I got error 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function find() in C:\xampp18\htdocs\demo\exp.php on line 6`
my question is that is this possible in `PHP` to handle this type error i.e. want to print `Line 2: 5` which is after the first if block. thanks in advance.

```
<?php 
$a=10;
if(true)
{
    echo "Line 1: ".$a/find();
}

if (true)
{
    $b=2;
    echo "<br>Line 2: ".$a/$b;
}
?>
```

Comment: No. This is a known fact - you can't continue execution after getting fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

that's not good idea. what about check whether `find()` is exist or not using `function_exists`. example:

```
<?php 
$a=10;
if(true) {
    echo "Line 1: " . (function_exists('find') ? $a/find() : $a);
}

if (true) {
    $b=2;
    echo "<br>Line 2: ".$a/$b;
}
?>
```

Comment: see this is a demo code. My aim is to continue execution even after a fatal error.